# not found error in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, sh

I am trying to run the following code in debian terminal.

```
    read var 
    if [$var -gt 0]; then
       echo "Greater than zero" 
    fi
```

When I give 45 as an input to the variable var, the terminal is showing the following error

```
   4:[ 45: Not Found
```

Why is the error coming and what is it's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces inside `[ and ]` are mandatory:

Try:

```
read var 
if [ "$var" -gt 0 ]; then
   echo "Greater than zero" 
fi
```

`/bin/[` is a binary in Unix that takes it's arguments from the string that comes after a space.

Comment: Thanks! never though a space could cause so much problem!

Comment: Yes Unix shell syntax is pretty rigid on use of spaces actually.

Comment: In modern shells, `[` is a shell builtin. You can run `type [` to find out if this is the case.

Comment: Yes true even `[[` can be used but space is still a requirement.